# Is it redundant to say "the jury is still out"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, redundancy

Should somebody who seeks to avoid stylistic infelicities related to redundancy refrain from using "still" in the construction "the jury is [] out"?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is valid to emphasize the length of an unresolved jury.  In an election, "The results are still pending." wouldn't be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The "still" part here means that there actually **is** a jury, and they haven't gone home **yet**. It is also implied that the jury has been sitting in the next room for quite some time.